# Oracle Constraints error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `x`, and added a new column `abc` of `number` data type. New column successfully loaded with null values into table `x`.

When I was trying to add the same column with `not null` constraint, its giving an error : "table must be empty to add mandatory (not null) column"

I expected an error because as there is no data in it, I can't use `not null` constraint. But, what was not expecting this error. Why must the table be empty to add that constraint ? Could some one explain ?

Comment: just imagine, what could database do with the existing nulls, when you mark something not null. So, the table has to be empty! Also,A ddl can never touch the existing data.. But for truncate, which actually just wipes out, the entire data.

Comment: @ Maheswaran ravisankar Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the null constraint is immediately violated as soon as you create the column.  You could perhaps supply a default value.

An empty table would not have this problem due to lack of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have data in the table, `NOT NULL` constraint is not violated. But if you have at least a single row, the constraint is violated because database have to create a column value for each row as `NULL`.

You can use a default value to overcome this issue:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD column_name NUMBER NOT NULL
DEFAULT '*';
```